# Change date format in PHP to include zeroes

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm new to PHP. I have a function called `jdf` and I want to convert Gregorian calendar dates to Jalali but this function returns an array like `2018/7/10` and I need something like `2018/07/10`. Is there anyway to change that format to the one I want?

Comment: Have you looked at the DateTime::format documentation?  I think the format string can specify that you want month with a leading zero.  Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Consider using proper formatting and punctuation as well as posting some actual code that you tried. You're likely to get a proportional quality in  your responses as you put into asking.

Comment: Yes it was my fault and i correct it thanks you very much it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use some already implemented libraries like

https://github.com/roozbeh360/Gregorian-Jalali-Date-Convertor/blob/master/gregorian_jalali.php

and pass year month and date of Gregorian calendar in `gregorian_to_jalali` function. In response, you will get year month and date of Jalali calendar, which then you can convert to string format as per your requirement
.